# hide field based on its value or value of another hidden field

Tags: entities

I need to hide a radio button field of a content type (not a form) only on the edit view based either on its own value or based on the value of another field that is already hidden.

Dependencies does not work,  I think because the other field is already hidden and because it does not allow the dependent and dependee field to be the same field.

Any ideas?

Comment: So, you are saying [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/ffc

Comment: Nice tip, i will find this module useful, however it did not resolve this issue as it hid the field on view content but not on edit content. i need the opposite.

Comment: Did you try this: https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Answer (score -2):

You may want to try hook_form_alter on that particular form. For example i had a case where i wanted a field to only show if it had more than one taxonomy term

```
    function members_form_members_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id){
if(count($form['field_church_']['und']['#options']) > 1){
 $form['field_church_']['und']['#required'] = TRUE;} 
     else{
    unset($form['field_church_']);}
return $form;}
```

Comment: Thanks, just a bit over my head. i can adapt the code, just not sure where to put it. In a new module?

Comment: You should use the [`#access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access) property instead of unsetting `$form` elements.

Comment: You are right. In my case i didn't want people to see the field.

Comment: Don't know why this answer is downvoted as it seems like the reasonable thing to do. I'm looking for a solution to this myself, but my case is a bit more complicated: I want to conditionally show a field based on another field, but these 2 fields are in a paragraph, which are referenced by a field in another paragraph which are referenced by a field in a content type. If anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears.